# How do I do this array lookup/replace with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I've got a 2D numpy array, `A` containing an index into another array, `B`. **What is a good way to get `C` from `A` and `B` using numpy?**

```
A = array([[1, 1, 0, 2],
           [1, 0, 0, 2],
           [1, 1, 0, 2]])

B = array([0, 5, 3])

C = array([[5, 5, 0, 3],
           [5, 0, 0, 3],
           [5, 5, 0, 3]])
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this `C = B[A]`. That's the beauty of numpy:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: A = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 2],
   ...:            [1, 0, 0, 2],
   ...:            [1, 1, 0, 2]])

In [3]: B = np.array([0, 5, 3])

In [4]: B[A]
Out[4]: 
array([[5, 5, 0, 3],
       [5, 0, 0, 3],
       [5, 5, 0, 3]])
```

Comment: Seems so obvious after you see it!

Comment: To spice things up a little, is it possible to conditionally index the array? Something like `B[(A>1) ? A : 0]`